# Trying to reference a script added to a project as a URI

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, uri, directory

This question should be simple but i am having a world of trouble getting something to work. First, here is my file structure:

[image]

I am simply trying to use this line of code:

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(string.Format("{0}", path), UriKind.Relative));
```

where

string path = @"Alliance\CommonUI\Dashboard\Scripts\JavaScript.js";

I am getting the following error:

[image]

if someone could steer me in the right direction, I would be appreciated. Note that this code was handed to me and may need to be altered. I am still learning...

Thanks

Comment: WHAT? what is javascript doing in a WPF Application?

Comment: HighCore, I am using Telerik controls. Telerik provides functionality to export charting as HTML. They provide the Javascript file with vague instructions. I have a demo with code, but they are using the scripts from a sample directory (not located in the project) which is making my life difficult.

Comment: then try setting the build action of the .js file to "Resource"

Comment: also, your URI is wrong. take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Comment: Thanks HighCore. My knowledge on URI's is, well, less than stellar. Let me read on the link you posted and I'll post back in a sec. I did change the properties of the js file to resource and got the same error, but of course there is another issue you have pointed out. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not being able to use this method. I was ultimately trying to export Telerik controls to HTML. Using Telerik's recommended methods (what I am trying to do in the question) proved impossible because the control contained another control that wouldn't pass enough information to the Javascript. I ended up embedding PNG's of the charting into HTML to solve the problem. Not as exactly like what we wanted to achieve, but not too bad. It gets the job done.